# How to get upvotes on old posts

Tags: support, downvotes, voting

I have a total of 3 downvotes on posts and my right to ask more questions got taken away. Fine. But looking back at the question, I truly do not see anything wrong with them (maybe someone could check that out because nobody commented on any of the posts?). However, even if I do fix the "problems" with my posts, how do I get people to upvote it since it is an old post?

Comment: Well first include a link to your question, so we can advise on what the problem is. And two, I think editing a post bumps it back to the top of the queue.

Comment: Or should that be "looking back at the questions" not "question"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456087/app-wont-run-on-adb
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368726/imagebutton-touch-event-still-called-after-dragging-finger-away

Comment: I don't think that you lost your voting rights due to the fact that you were downvoted three times.

Comment: I have edited one of your questions. Please check if I didn't change the intent.

Comment: You also have several deleted questions, some of which are downvoted. *Those count against you too*.

Comment: Just earn it back, 11 points should not be a major obstacle.  2 helpful votes or 6 approved edits is all it takes.  Consider editing your question btw, looks like users here think you lost your question privilege.  Sounded to me like you complained about the close vote privilege.

Answer (score 2):

The question score is somehow proportional to the number of people to whom you helped. If your answer is downvoted you can pick one out of three solutions:

1. Do nothing.
2. Delete the answer.
3. Edit the answer.

If you edit your answer (add something valuable what can help the others) you might get upvoted. Make sure that you read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It's an article which describes how to write good answers. The question on which an answer was edited is bumped to the top of the questions, so people might see your edit and vote up if it's valuable.

Stack Overflow rewards those who remove bad answers because it saves time to people who read answers below the question. You can even be rewarded a badge for removing a bad answer.

Apart from the above, remember that it's much better to prevent than to heal so please think twice before answering.

On questions, you lose the option to delete. My advice is to leave it as it is. Focus on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take a lesson. Remember that a question should be clear, as short as possible and should provide results of your research on the problem. In this question you should add a screen shot of the message that you have lost vote privilege - it would be easier to give you the reason.

I don't think that you have lost your vote privilege due to the fact that you have been downvoted few times. Stack Overflow bases on voting. What might have happened is that you have already voted 40 times today. Wait till tomorrow and the problem should disappear.

Comment: Sorry, I believe I should have made myself a bit more specific to my case. I was talking more about posing questions and not answering questions (although that is of course related)

Comment: @Eames most of the answer here is still relevant :). The how to answer link could be an how to ask link instead, but your options are pretty much the same ^^. And yeah, no way voting rights changes because of downvotes on your content.